# How to change the background color of list items/elements in a nav bar using JQuery?

Tags: jquery, css

I am just learning the JQuery and for the sake of testing my self I was creating a simple webpage having a nav-bar consists of list elements, and a header and footer. I want to change the background colors of the list elements of nav-bar whenever I click any item.

I have tried using the `$(id-name)` selector and .click() method to change the background color, but it just changes the background color of text, not the whole element containing the padding, width/height and borders etc.

**Here is my HTML Code:**

```
<div id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li id="t1" ><a style="background-color: #505152;" href="#">ELEMENT 1</a></li>
        <li id="t2"><a href="#">ELEMENT 2</a></li>
        <li id="t3"><a href="#">ELEMENT 3</a></li>
        <li id="t4"><a href="#">ELEMENT 4</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="body">
    <div id="text1" class="allText">This is Text 1</div>

    <div id="text2" class="allText" style="display: none;" >This is text 2</div>

    <div id="text3" class="allText"  style="display: none;">This is text 3</div>

    <div id="text4" class="allText"  style="display: none;">This is text 4</div>
</div>
```

**Here is my CSS Code:**

```
body{
    font-family: Helvetica;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#body{
    background-color: #fcfcfc;
    width: 75%;
    float: left;;
    height: 450;
}

#nav{
    background-color: #e1e4e6;
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
    height: 440px;
}

ul{
    list-style: none;
}

ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 20px;
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
    font-style: italic;
}

ul li{
    margin-top: 40px;
}
```

**Here is my JQuery Code:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#text1").css("background-color", "#38ceff");

    console.log("enter in script");

    $("#t1").click(function(){
        $("li").eq(0).css("background-color", "#505152");
        $("li").eq(1).css("background-color", "black");
        $("li").eq(2).css("background-color", "black");
        $("li").eq(3).css("background-color", "black");

        $("#text1").show();
        $("#text2").hide();
        $("#text3").hide();
        $("#text4").hide();
    });

    $("#t2").click(function(){
        $("li").eq(0).css("background-color", "black");
        $("li").eq(1).css("background-color", "#505152");
        $("li").eq(2).css("background-color", "black");
        $("li").eq(3).css("background-color", "black");

        $("#text1").hide();
        $("#text2").show();
        $("#text3").hide();
        $("#text4").hide();
    });

    $("#t3").click(function(){
        $("li").eq(0).css("background-color", "black");
        $("li").eq(1).css("background-color", "black");
        $("li").eq(2).css("background-color", "#505152");
        $("li").eq(3).css("background-color", "black");

        $("#text1").hide();
        $("#text2").hide();
        $("#text3").show();
        $("#text4").hide();
    });

    $("#t4").click(function(){
        $("li").eq(0).css("background-color", "black");
        $("li").eq(1).css("background-color", "black");
        $("li").eq(2).css("background-color", "black");
        $("li").eq(3).css("background-color", "#505152");

        $("#text1").hide();
        $("#text2").hide();
        $("#text3").hide();
        $("#text4").show();
    });
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're missing some closing brackets in your css.

Comment: @Tuneer thanks, I have corrected the code, but I still does get the desired behavior, it changes the background-color of the text not the whole list element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(function(){
    $("#text1").css("background-color", "#38ceff");

    console.log("enter in script");

    $("#t1").click(function(){
        $("li a").eq(0).css("background-color", "#505152");
  $("li a").eq(1).css("background-color", "black");
        $("li a").eq(2).css("background-color", "black");
        $("li a").eq(3).css("background-color", "black");

        $("#text1").show();
        $("#text2").hide();
        $("#text3").hide();
        $("#text4").hide();
    });

    $("#t2").click(function(){
        $("li a").eq(0).css("background-color", "black");
        $("li a").eq(1).css("background-color", "#505152");
        $("li a").eq(2).css("background-color", "black");
        $("li a").eq(3).css("background-color", "black");

        $("#text1").hide();
        $("#text2").show();
        $("#text3").hide();
        $("#text4").hide();
    });

    $("#t3").click(function(){
        $("li a").eq(0).css("background-color", "black");
        $("li a").eq(1).css("background-color", "black");
        $("li a").eq(2).css("background-color", "#505152");
        $("li a").eq(3).css("background-color", "black");

        $("#text1").hide();
        $("#text2").hide();
        $("#text3").show();
        $("#text4").hide();
    });

    $("#t4").click(function(){
        $("li a").eq(0).css("background-color", "black");
        $("li a").eq(1).css("background-color", "black");
        $("li a").eq(2).css("background-color", "black");
        $("li a").eq(3).css("background-color", "#505152");

        $("#text1").hide();
        $("#text2").hide();
        $("#text3").hide();
        $("#text4").show();
    });
});
```

```css
body{
    font-family: Helvetica;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#body{
    background-color: #fcfcfc;
    width: 75%;
    float: left;;
    height: 450;
}

#nav{
    background-color: #e1e4e6;
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
    height: 440px;
}

ul{
    list-style: none;
}

ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 20px;
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
    font-style: italic;
}

ul li{
    margin-top: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li id="t1" ><a style="background-color: #505152;" href="#">ELEMENT 1</a></li>
        <li id="t2"><a href="#">ELEMENT 2</a></li>
        <li id="t3"><a href="#">ELEMENT 3</a></li>
        <li id="t4"><a href="#">ELEMENT 4</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="body">
    <div id="text1" class="allText">This is Text 1</div>

    <div id="text2" class="allText" style="display: none;" >This is text 2</div>

    <div id="text3" class="allText"  style="display: none;">This is text 3</div>

    <div id="text4" class="allText"  style="display: none;">This is text 4</div>
</div>
```

Here is your javascript

```
 $("#text1").css("background-color", "#38ceff");

console.log("enter in script");

$("#t1").click(function(){
    $("li a").eq(0).css("background-color", "#505152");
    $("li a").eq(1).css("background-color", "black");
    $("li a").eq(2).css("background-color", "black");
    $("li a").eq(3).css("background-color", "black");

    $("#text1").show();
    $("#text2").hide();
    $("#text3").hide();
    $("#text4").hide();
});

$("#t2").click(function(){
    $("li a").eq(0).css("background-color", "black");
    $("li a").eq(1).css("background-color", "#505152");
    $("li a").eq(2).css("background-color", "black");
    $("li a").eq(3).css("background-color", "black");

    $("#text1").hide();
    $("#text2").show();
    $("#text3").hide();
    $("#text4").hide();
});

$("#t3").click(function(){
    $("li a").eq(0).css("background-color", "black");
    $("li a").eq(1).css("background-color", "black");
    $("li a").eq(2).css("background-color", "#505152");
    $("li a").eq(3).css("background-color", "black");

    $("#text1").hide();
    $("#text2").hide();
    $("#text3").show();
    $("#text4").hide();
});

$("#t4").click(function(){
    $("li a").eq(0).css("background-color", "black");
    $("li a").eq(1).css("background-color", "black");
    $("li a").eq(2).css("background-color", "black");
    $("li a").eq(3).css("background-color", "#505152");

    $("#text1").hide();
    $("#text2").hide();
    $("#text3").hide();
    $("#text4").show();
});
```

});

Comment: I have corrected it, but it still only changes the background-color of the text not the whole list element.

Comment: thanks a lot for the help mate, it solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#nav li a').on('click', function(){
    $('li a.orange').removeClass('orange');
    $(this).addClass('orange');
});
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Helvetica;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#body {
  background-color: #fcfcfc;
  width: 75%;
  float: left;
  ;
  height: 450;
}

#nav {
  background-color: #e1e4e6;
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
  height: 440px;
}

.orange {
  background-color: #ffa500;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 20px;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  font-style: italic;
}

ul li {
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.orange {
  background-color: #ffa500;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="nav">
  <ul>
    <li id="t1"><a style="background-color: #505152;" href="#">ELEMENT 1</a></li>
    <li id="t2"><a href="#">ELEMENT 2</a></li>
    <li id="t3"><a href="#">ELEMENT 3</a></li>
    <li id="t4"><a href="#">ELEMENT 4</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="body">
  <div id="text1" class="allText">This is Text 1</div>

  <div id="text2" class="allText" style="display: none;">This is text 2</div>

  <div id="text3" class="allText" style="display: none;">This is text 3</div>

  <div id="text4" class="allText" style="display: none;">This is text 4</div>
</div>
```

how about doing it like this. this should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

you don't select the `<li>` element, you select the `<a>` tag inside the `<li>`.

change this code:

```
$("li").eq(2).css("background-color", "#505152");
```

to this code:

```
$("li a").eq(2).css("background-color", "#505152");
```

Comment: Thanks @Mike, but Its the otherway around, I have suggested you the edit.